# Issues with displaying dynamic OpenGL VBO

Tags: opengl, dynamic, vbo

I have been working with VBOs in OpenGL, and I apparently don't understand what I'm even doing wrong here. I want to display a VBO with text in it that is updated each frame. The goal this time is for a FPS counter, but other applications are definitely viable.

Down to the actual code: I can get it to work just fine if I set up the VBOs in my initialization function and then draw it in the rendering function. If I try and edit it in the draw function, however, nothing displays. While debugging I have found that all of the vectors containing the data are exactly correct (I even updated the VBO with the same text and the vectors were indeed identical), so the issue must be with my handling of VBOs, and not the data inside of them.

Here is the initialization/rendering commands:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &pntvbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pntvbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, newpoints.size() * sizeof(vec3f), &newpoints[0], GL_STREAM_DRAW);


glGenBuffers(1, &indvbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indvbo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, newindex.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), &newindex[0], GL_STREAM_DRAW);
```

I also tried this, but with no success:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pntvbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, newpoints.size() * sizeof(vec3f), NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, newpoints.size() * sizeof(vec3f), &newpoints[0]);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indvbo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, newindex.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,0, newindex.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), &newindex[0]);
```

And the draw command itself:

```
glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE5);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &newtexts[0]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pntvbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indvbo);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,sizeof(vec3f),0);    

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, newindex.size() , GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0); 
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

I'm sure I'm doing SOMETHING wrong here, but I just can't figure out for the life of me as to what it is. As I said, everything works out fine if I only initialize or edit the VBO in the initialization function of my program, but once those same functions are put into the rendering function nothing displays. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One problem is that you use `glEnable()` instead of `glEnableClientState()` for `GL_TEX_COORD_ARRAY`. But I don't think that should stop it from rendering anything at all.

Comment: My mistake. That unfortunately did not fix anything. Are there no other obvious problems? I don't understand what I'm messing up with.

Comment: @user2446445L The problem is probably in the parts of the code you didn't paste. OpenGL is a state machine. It is hard to tell which state it is in if only a few snippets are known.

Comment: You are correct with it being something else that is incorrect. I have managed to get it to display properly, but only in a very weird instance in my code. Further testing will be needed to see what is causing these issues.